# Group by According to three tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have three tables

```
tbl_worker

City   WorkerName     Job
 10     Raymond    Carpenter
 10     Sara       Programmer 
 11     John       Painter
 11     Alice      Booker

tbl_workshop

City    WorkshopName   
 10       Dell         
 11       Apple
 10       Sony 

Tbl_city
  Id    Name
  10    Mexico
  11    Sydney
```

Now I want such a result:

```
City    WorkersQty    WorkshopQry
 Mexico     2               2
 Sydney     2               1
```

The result returns the quantity of workers and workshops which are registered in different cities.
what query should I write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the `tbl_workshop` and `tbl_worker` tables individually, then use a `LEFT JOIN` to get the results:

```
SELECT c.City,
    k.Cnt AS WorkersQty,
    w.Cnt AS WorkshopQry
FROM Tbl_city c
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT City, COUNT(*) Cnt
    FROM tbl_worker
    GROUP BY City
    ) k ON c.ID = k.City
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT City, COUNT(*) Cnt
    FROM tbl_workshop
    GROUP BY City
    ) w ON c.ID = w.City
```

If you want to only show the cities that have workshop's or workers, add:

```
WHERE k.Cnt > 0 OR w.Cnt > 0
```

Comment: I know about left join but could you explain me about it here specially in the second join.

Comment: @raymond The reason why we need to use a `LEFT` join as apposed to a `INNER` join is to show data in the case that a city either has 0 workers, or 0 workshops.

Answer (score 0):

Use Dense_rank to get the number of workshops or workers

```
SELECT city, MAX(WorkshopQty) AS WorkshopQty , MAX(WorkersQty) AS WorkersQty
FROM (
        SELECT c.name AS City, 
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY WorkshopName) AS WorkshopQty,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY c.id ORDER BY WorkerName) AS WorkersQty  
        FROM tbl_city c
        INNER JOIN tbl_workshop s ON s.city = c.id
        INNER JOIN tbl_worker w ON w.city = c.id
    ) s
GROUP BY City
```